# Sitecore Web Service Url Length

Tags: sitecore

So for some reason sitecore seems to be rejecting the longer version of this url `http://site1.com/sitecore%20modules/shell/service.svc/terms/a new term to find for all/` with error:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length]
   System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy) +14652406
   Sitecore.Web.RequestUrl.get_ItemPath() +157
   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.GetItemPath(HttpRequestArgs args, SiteContext context) +55
   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.UpdatePaths(HttpRequestArgs args, SiteContext site) +88
   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs args) +75
   (Object , Object[] ) +83
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +191
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs ) +457
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

But the url `http://site1.com/sitecore%20modules/shell/service.svc/terms/a new term to find/` seems to work fine. Also when I add the url in `IgnoreUrlPrefix`, it seems to be loosing the sitecore context altogether.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set any max lengths for the url in your web.config, either in requestFiltering or your service bindings? What happens if you move the service to the root folder and make the same request?

Comment: The requestFiltering is set to <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" /> 
The error is coming from Sitecore SiteResolver so I would assume service binding should have nothing to do with it?

Comment: If I move it to root, it will work but loses sitecore context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem,and if I choose a short name for my webmethod works fine.  With long method name I get same error like you .

I didn't find a reason why is this behavior. 
   Update :

I asked Sitecore Support about this issue , and they send me this [link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20v5/sitecore%20cms%206/releasenotes/knownissues%20recommended/errors%20when%20the%20url%20includes%20path%20info.aspx) .

This is the code they provide :

```
 public class SiteResolver : SiteResolver
  {
    protected override void UpdatePaths(HttpRequestArgs args, SiteContext site)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo))
      {
        string filePath = args.Url.FilePath;
        int length = filePath.LastIndexOf('.');
        int num = filePath.LastIndexOf('/');
        args.Url.ItemPath = length >= 0 ? (length >= num ? filePath.Substring(0, length) : filePath) : filePath;
      }
      args.StartPath = site.StartPath;
      args.Url.ItemPath = this.GetItemPath(args, site);
      site.Request.ItemPath = args.Url.ItemPath;
      args.Url.FilePath = this.GetFilePath(args, site);
      site.Request.FilePath = args.Url.FilePath;
    }
  }
```

To works fine, IgnoreUrlPrefixes should not contains Asxm webservice path, and siteresolver configuration must be:

```
   <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <patch:attribute name="type">yourNamespace.CustomSiteResolver,yourAssembly</patch:attribute>
    </processor>
```

Comment: When I include it in IgnoreUrlPrefixes, I seem to loosing the sitecore context. I put the service inside sitecore modules folder so that I could get sitecore context.

Comment: Is that the right way to patch? I am seeing configuration error.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks for help. This seems to be working great!